# FCM in android notification payload , event_time

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

i want to make the notification push on like maybe 5 minute after i run this http function. delete the `event_time` from the jsaon of notification i will  receive the push notification  that have timeline now, but if i hard code the `event_time` the time will show 50 year ago since epoch time , event i put 999 for the year it just increase by 2 year . i dint get it at all. then found Timestapm format in google and firebase so  use it and the android got error whil parsing the json payload said cant fine field something . have any idea to format the Zulu RC399 time format?

```
pp.get('/sendCloudMessageReminderActivation', async (req, res) => {
    const x = req.query.userUID;
    const xstr = String(x);
    const zxcv = admin.firestore().collection('user').doc(xstr);
    const xoxo = await zxcv.get();
    var today = new Date();
    // today.setHours(today.getHours()+1);
    today.setHours(today.getHours()+8);
    // today.setFullYear(today.getFullYear()+50);
    var xoxocode;
    console.log(today+'saya saya sebelum cagbge');

    // today =  ISODateString(today);
    const timestamp = admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(today);
    console.log(timestamp.nanoseconds +'siniiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii');






    if (xoxo!==null) {

        xoxocode= await xoxo.data().cloudMessagingToken;
        const message = {
            notification: {
                title: 'your account is still in active state',
                body: 'Tap here to check it out!'
            },
            android:{
                priority:'high',
                // important : 'MAX',
                notification:{
                    notification_priority: "PRIORITY_MAX",
                    event_time: timestamp,// when ever i cahnge this event use ZULU RC339 format i still give my 50 year ago notification. i did my research but cant figure out how to do this ,
                    default_sound: true,

                    // notification_priority: PRIORITY_MAX
                }
            },
            token: xoxocode
          };


        // res.status(200).send('authorized');

        const respondfrommesage = admin.messaging().send(message);
        console.log(respondfrommesage);


        res.status(200).send('message send notification');


    }

    res.end();


  });
```

Comment: Have you managed to solve the problem?

Comment: no i didn't, i cut of this feature, since it just my FYP project and i my time is limited, but will use this FMC feature back in future .

Comment: I reported this issue to Firebase, they reproduced it and are planning to fix it, but they cannot provide any timeline for that.

Answer (score 1):

`Zulu` is not a time format. It's a `time zone`. Zulu is just another name for `UTC`.

As per this [article](https://www.thoughtco.com/zulu-time-and-coordinated-universal-time-3444435):

> Another name for UTC Time is "Zulu" or "Z Time."

Now, about the timestamp value. If you are creating a Date object and use `milliseconds` or `nanoseconds` property of a date, it will always give you the difference in respective property type (mills/nano),

From the time you created the instance and [starting time of UNIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) which is `1 January 1970`.

It has been `50 years` as of `1st Jan, 2020`. Hence the `50` year difference in the `event_time`.

If you have any other doubts let me know.

Comment: okey my mistake for that Zulu time zone, just read about it Zulu got 0000 time format and i use Malaysia or Singapore got 0080 time format right , but in the even_time field ,
i also tried : event_time: "2020-01-01T23:00:00Z", but still get  19-01-1970,, how actually android count this ?

Comment: I have the same problem with python firebase admin and also sending notification from google playground. I'm thinking that could be an android problem